# How do I add PyTorch w/ CUDA to Dask Helm Chart

Tags: pytorch, conda, dask, kubernetes-helm

**Install PyTorch compiled for CUDA into the Dask helm chart, and it failed:**

Install PyTorch for CUDA per the instructions on `pytorch.org` (see image below).

*Dask helm chart example fails:*

```
- name: EXTRA_CONDA_PACKAGES
    value: "pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.0 -c pytorch"
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to check out the [RAPIDS helm chart](https://helm.rapids.ai/), which is an extension of the Dask helm chart but with additional GPU support.

**Install at runtime**

The [RAPIDS Docker images](https://hub.docker.com/r/rapidsai/rapidsai/) also support the same `EXTRA_PIP_PACKAGES`, `EXTRA_CONDA_PACKAGES` and `EXTRA_APT_PACKAGES` that the Dask Docker images do.

```yaml
# config.yaml
dask:
  scheduler:
    image:
      repository: rapidsai/rapidsai
      tag: cuda11.0-runtime-ubuntu18.04-py3.8

  worker:
    image:
      repository: rapidsai/rapidsai
      tag: cuda11.0-runtime-ubuntu18.04-py3.8
    env:
      - name: EXTRA_CONDA_PACKAGES
        value: "-c pytorch pytorch torchvision torchaudio"

  # If you're using the bundled Jupyter Lab instance you probably want to install these here too
  jupyter:
    image:
      repository: rapidsai/rapidsai
      tag: cuda11.0-runtime-ubuntu18.04-py3.8
    env:
      - name: EXTRA_CONDA_PACKAGES
        value: "-c pytorch pytorch torchvision torchaudio"
```

```sh
$ helm install rapidstest rapidsai/rapidsai -f config.yaml
```

**Install ahead of time**

The above approach means the dependencies will be installed every time a worker starts. Therefore you may prefer to create your own custom Docker image with these dependencies already included.

```
# Dockerfile
FROM rapidsai/rapidsai:cuda11.0-runtime-ubuntu18.04-py3.8

RUN conda install -n rapids -c pytorch pytorch torchvision torchaudio
```

```sh
$ docker build -t jacobtomlinson/customrapids:latest .
$ docker push jacobtomlinson/customrapids:latest
```

```yaml
# config.yaml
dask:
  scheduler:
    image:
      repository: jacobtomlinson/customrapids
      tag: latest

  worker:
    image:
      repository: jacobtomlinson/customrapids
      tag: latest

  # If you're using the bundled Jupyter Lab instance you probably want to install these here too
  jupyter:
    image:
      repository: jacobtomlinson/customrapids
      tag: latest
```

```sh
$ helm install rapidstest rapidsai/rapidsai -f config.yaml
```